# Getting value from table was empty

Tags: jquery, html-table

Firstly I have a form, this is part from my form code:

```
<td class="td1" width="15%" id="td00">abc</td>
<td class="td1" width="15%" id="td01">efg</td>
```

from jQuery, I want pass the value of the td to my server via ajax.

If I use:

```
var name=$('#td00').val();
```

I get an empty value, if this is not a table but a text input, I can get value like this, but now it not working in table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.text()` or `.html()`

```
var name=$('#td00').text();
```

- `.html()` will get the **html** content of the element
- `.text()` will get the **text** content of the element
- `.val()` works for `<input/>` `<select/>` `<textarea/>` .It gets the property value of those elements.

Documentation

1. [.Val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
2. [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
3. [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: It works, but how is the difference between those, .val(), .html(), .text()?

Comment: .val() works for <input/> <select/> <textarea/> it gets the property value of those elements. I've written about .html() and .text() in the answer